# Prevent user from selecting custom UIPickerView Swift 2.x

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uipickerview

I have a custom UIPickerView that has several rows.
Under some conditions I'd like to disable the use of only a few of them from changing.
Is it possible to achieve that?
I took a look around but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a logic in a function:

[image: UIPickerView Class apple reference]

In this function you will say how many rows will be created in your custom picker view. In my example I have an array containing two values, for example:

```
var pickerStr = ["Event","Place"]

///Number of rows in category picker
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     return pickerStr.count
}
```

Inside on this function you just need create your logic to show how many datas you need.

to more informations you can find here: [UIPickerViewClassReference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/numberOfRowsInComponent:)